# Javadoc "mouse over" view

Tags: java, formatting, javadoc

I am writing javadoc comments for some of my code and I ran into a problem. When I "mouse over" a function that I have documented I am able to see the description that I wrote in the javadoc comment, however it does not appear the same as when I mouse over a standard library function such as `System.out.println()`. The given function on mouse over appears something like this:

**println**
`public void println()`
description here

but although my functions appear in a very similar fashion in javadoc view, on mouse over they do not automatically format themselves as in the example above and only the description written in the comment shows up. I would like to know how to be able to have my javadoc comments appear like that on mouse over as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a whole markup used for writing JavaDoc instead of just plaintext descriptions. The reason there's looks different is because they're using the markup to make it look better. Here's an example from the source:

```
/**
* Prints a String and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
* though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
* <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
*
* @param x  The <code>String</code> to be printed.
*/
public void println(String x) {
   synchronized (this) {
      print(x);
      newLine();
   }
}
```

Note the use of markup like @param and @link. Here's Oracle's guide to writing markup: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html